# Picklist values for non supported languages

Tags: customization

There is only one supported German language in SFDC.  However, we have a need to show picklists in different national varieties of German viz. Austrian German, Swiss German.  What's the easiest way to do this?  We are currently thinking of using dependent picklists for this.  Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the PM for language support at Salesforce.com.  This is actually one of the use cases for Platform languages.  We don't currently support German variants but we could add them in the Summer release.  This would allow users to select a German variant as their language and all labels not customized by you would fall through to our standard German translations.  You would be able to rename tabs, translate custom objects and labels as well as picklist values into the supported variants.  Would that solve your issue?
Solving this with current technology could be as simple as a dependent picklist - and if you only need this in a few places that is what I'd recommend.  You could do something more complex with profiles and record types but it is likely overkill in this situation.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, yes that's exactly what we need

Comment: Any update on when this might come out?